# ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence in CVXPY minimize function

Tags: python, optimization, minimize, cvxpy, convex-optimization

I tried to solve a convex problem with cvxpy as below.

```
        import cvxpy as cp
        import numpy as np

        # Problem data.
        Q = np.array([[13, 12, -2], [12, 17, 6], [-2, 6, 12]])
        q = np.array([[-22, -14.5, 13]])
        r = 1

        # Construct the problem.
        x = cp.Variable((3,1))
        objective = cp.Minimize(np.dot(np.dot(x.T, Q), x) + np.dot(q, x) + r)

        constraints = [0 <= x[0:], x[0:] <= 1]
        prob = cp.Problem(objective, constraints)

        # The optimal objective value is returned by `prob.solve()`.
        result = prob.solve()
        # The optimal value for x is stored in `x.value`.
        print(x.value)
        # The optimal Lagrange multiplier for a constraint is stored in
        # `constraint.dual_value`.
        print(constraints[0].dual_value)
```

However, I get this error:

```
        ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.
```

I don't know why this error occurs because everything else seems to work.

Edit: Please let me know if the problem statement is needed.

Comment: The error is incomplete and the stacktrace probably even shows the problematic line. Furthermore you either did something wrong when copy-pasting that code or your cvxpy version is old as `cp.Variable(3,1)` should not do.

Comment: Your problem in general howewer is that you are using cvxpy in a wrong way: cvxpy *provides atomic functions* and *overloads* some operators such that it can generate some *expression-graph* internally. Using non-cvxpy stuff in expressions passed to cvxpy does not allow that. `np.dot` should not be there. Reason 1: cvxpy does not know what to do with it (it's external stuff) Reason 2: np.dot() is a less algebraic expression, while cvxpy allows allows algebraic expr like `A*x` (mat-vec mul), for example, where numpy would need dot. Reason 3: You want cvxpy's `quad_form` expression i suppose.

Comment: @sascha Thank you for your comment. I have missed out another pair of brackets around x = cp.Variable(3,1). I have since added them in for proper debugging. Additionally, I will look into the reasons you provided to debug.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See comments above:

```
import cvxpy as cp
import numpy as np

# Problem data.
Q = np.array([[13, 12, -2], [12, 17, 6], [-2, 6, 12]])
q = np.array([[-22, -14.5, 13]])
r = 1

# Construct the problem.
x = cp.Variable((3,1))

# WE CAN'T USE NUMPY'S DOT
# ALSO: WE WANT TO EXPRESS AS MUCH STRUCTURE AS POSSIBLE -> cp.quad_form()!
# q*x is cvxpy-compatible expression -> quite algebraic compared to numpy
# -------------------------------------------------------------------------
objective = cp.Minimize(cp.quad_form(x, Q) + q*x + r)

# ORIGINAL SLICING IS A NO-OP
# ---------------------------
constraints = [0 <= x, x <= 1]

prob = cp.Problem(objective, constraints)

        # The optimal objective value is returned by `prob.solve()`.
result = prob.solve()
        # The optimal value for x is stored in `x.value`.
print(x.value)
        # The optimal Lagrange multiplier for a constraint is stored in
        # `constraint.dual_value`.
print(constraints[0].dual_value)
```

Output:

```
[[ 8.46153846e-01]
[-6.34467676e-25]
[-1.92032635e-25]]
[[0.        ]
[5.80769231]
[9.61538462]]
```